# ReactJS app EC2 router 404

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, react-router

I have react app bases on https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot.
I have url there: /about
If I go directly to this url via development mode or production on localhost it works fine.
But in EC2 instance via nginx I got error:

> 404 Not Found
>
> nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        root /home/ubuntu/www/example;
        index index.html index.htm;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";        
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:AES256+ECDHE';

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
}
```

how to properly configure it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Heh I just found finally smth in internet :)

https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/nginx.html

Works fine.

I was missing good locations:

```
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
      # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name /var/www/example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;      

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
      # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server